# sending XMR with MyMonero, to low fee, long time stuck

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mymonero, transaction-fees

A month ago I sent XMR using MyMonero to recipient (MM was my first wallet and default to making transaction). Unfortunately I used a too low of a fee. My transaction at this moment is still frozen :(. I have hash of the transaction (af97f53681598fa6fe517d23f26bd197e95b415f9863ce0ccb9984a22c739017) and nothing else. After that I imported wallet to GUI with keys from MyMonero. I haven't 25 seed, only 13. Option rescan_bc in monero-wallet-cli show status OUT of this transaction. Monero GUI show ID on the history. Source go to the limbo? Any chance to fix this situation?

Answer (score 2):

That transaction was successfully sent [on the 9th of December](https://xmrchain.net/search?value=af97f53681598fa6fe517d23f26bd197e95b415f9863ce0ccb9984a22c739017), more than a month ago. So the xmr is available to whoever owns the recipient address.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. Can I do anything to complete this transaction now?

Comment: It is already complete...

Comment: @possiethief Either you used the correct destination address and the recipient *has* received the xmr, or you used an incorrect address and the xmr you sent are lost. If the recipient required a payment ID (for example if it's an exchange) and you did not use one, the recipient may not be able to identify the payment you sent. In that case you probably need to talk to them and provide the transaction id so that they know that this specific transaction was sent by you.

Comment: Assylias thanks a lot one more time, your explanation is very very usefull, pzdr!